# If a button appears on a page, automatically click it

Tags: javascript, greasekit

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="PrmryBtnMed"
 id = "VERYLONGTEXT"

onclick="$(this).parents('form').submit(); return false;"><span>Dispatch to this address</span></a>
```

If I was to give instructions to a human, I would say:

1. look for a `<span>Dispatch to this address</span>` link; if it appears click it. (if there is more than one such link (for example there are two) just click the first one (or any of them)

I am using Greasekit, so I am looking to do this using JavaScript.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated:** Now checks contents of element

```
var el = document.querySelector(".PrmryBtnMed"); //should only return first one
if (el && (el.textContent.trim() == 'Dispatch to this address')) {
  el.click();
}
```

Have a look at the [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelector) and [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.textContent) for more information

I also added a JsFiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/NrGVq/1/

---

A different approach is to search the whole page, in case it's not inside the matched element

```
var inPage = document.documentElement.innerHTML.indexOf('text to search') > 0,
    el = document.querySelector(".PrmryBtnMed");

if (inPage && el) el.click();
```

Comment: Thanks very much, but I'm using **Greasekit** so I'm not sure i can use JQuery. (Can it be done with javascript?) (or, does anyone know **how to load JQuery into greasekit**? I'm going to try and google the answer)

Comment: this is not jQuery, this is native javascript. Works in modern browsers and IE8+

Comment: If you still want to add jQuery to greasekit, for other uses, have a look at http://thepugautomatic.com/2009/07/jquery-in-greasekit/

Comment: Ah, it's native JavaScript, **I stand corrected**. However, upon reflection, I can't use this method as will get undesired clicks on similar pages (that also use `PrmryBtnMed`). Is it possible for the code to only run if `Select a shipping address` appears on the page? Alternately, if it's easier to search for a single word, what if the word `Eskdale` appears... only then click the button. (Thanks!)

Comment: Updated my answer to search for text both inside the element or anywhere in the page

Comment: I need to tweak this: the class name has changed from `PrmryBtnMed` to `PrmryBtnMed ApricotWheat`. As a result, what changes do I need to make to `el = document.querySelector(".PrmryBtnMed”);` to make it work with the apricot thing, please?

Comment: `document.querySelector(".PrmryBtnMed")` will pickup any elements that have `PrmryBtnMed` as a class. If you want *only* the elements that have both classes use `document.querySelector(".PrmryBtnMed.ApricotWheat")`