# How to autoclick that is in this set position (of a known table class)

Tags: javascript

I'm using Greasekit so need this to be in Javascript.

I want to be able to automatically click the link where it says `25` below. However, **the link is not always 25**, it is sometimes (say) 21 or 26 (depending on how long the newsletter is).
What remains constant is that the link is always in the same position / place on the page. It is ALWAYS the one before `Next >` and after `3`

```
<table class="v_page_nav" border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<tr>
<td width="100%">Showing 1-25 of 610 Results</td>
<td><span style="color: #999999">< Previous</span> | Page:</td>
<td class="on">
<a href="/wine/newsletter?ie=UTF8&amp;page=1" id="pagination-page-1">1</a></td>
<td class="off">
<a href="/wine/newsletter?ie=UTF8&amp;page=2" id="pagination-page-2">2</a></td>
<td class="off">
<a href="/wine/newsletter?ie=UTF8&amp;page=3" id="pagination-page-3">3</a></td>
<td>...</td>
<td>
<a href="/wine/newsletter?ie=UTF8&amp;page=25" id="pagination-page-25">25</a></td>
<td>| <a href="/wine/newsletter?ie=UTF8&amp;page=2" id="pagination-next-link">Next ></a>      </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

As I was saying... **the link is not always 25**, it is sometimes (say) 13 or 29 (depending on how long the newsletter is).
What remains constant is that the link is always in the same position / place on the page. It is ALWAYS the one before `Next >` and after `3`

Can I, using code, always find and then click on the appropriate link?

## If i was instructing human

I would start by saying to find table class `v_page_nav`
Then, scan your eyes right and look for the link `Next >`. Click the link that immediately precedes it: it will always be a number (and that number will always be higher than the numbers on the left of it).

How do I achieve the same thing in code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get all of the anchors on the page, loop through them, then return the one right before "Next"

```
function getPreviousLink(){
    var nextLink = document.getElementById('pagination-next-link'); 
    var links = document.getElementsByClassName('v_page_nav')[0].getElementsByTagName("a");

    for(var i=0; i < links.length; i++){
        if(links[i] == nextLink) { return links[i-1]; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried the code and it doesn't seem to work, sadly. Please tell me, did you include the instruction to do the click? (If you didn't could you kindly update).

Comment: (It is a large web page, so I wonder if it's worth telling the code jump straight to that table class?)

Comment: Added code to limit the scope to the table class. To do the actual click is more complicated in pure javascript. See this question for more information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/143747/is-it-possible-to-trigger-a-links-or-any-elements-click-event-through-javasc

Comment: Oh, really? i am able to click a button with just one line of code: `if (inPage && el) el.click();` (taken from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16191804/if-a-button-appears-on-a-page-automatically-click-it)  I shall try to get my head around the page you linked to

Comment: Okay, so do I add the following to the end: `function fireEvent(element,event) {` (and the lines below it)?

Comment: I appended the code to your answer. I'm going to try it out now.

Comment: (didn't work) I'll go and re-read all the documentation and links you kindly provided.

Comment: el.click() does appear to work in Chrome and Firefox. I was afraid it was IE-specific. Here's a fiddle with the above code and a click event firing. http://jsfiddle.net/mK2d2/

Comment: [to anyone] As a twist, is it possible to open this in a new window? (Not essential, I'm just curious to know how). (I tried to google it and all i found was advice to `<a href="some.htm" target="_blank">Link Text</a>` but that doesn't seem to apply here, as it's javascript, not html.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30284/discussion-between-ted-and-chris-hendry)